# How to access parent method from field?

Tags: java

I have tree classes.

```
class MyObject{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        here I need to call method add from class base.
    }
}

class base
{
    protected final void add(){}      
}

class extended extends base {
    private MyObject pObject = new MyObject();
    ...
    {
        pObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I could have created class for each variation that extends class extended, but the type what I need to use becomes available only after class extended is already initiated.

How do I call `base.add()` from *MyObject* inner method?

Comment: The `protected` modifier allows same-class (including sub classes) and same-package access, so as long as `class MyObject` and `class base` are in the same package, you can access `base.add()` on an instance of `base`.  As a side note, class names should begin with capitals as is dictated by Java conventions.

Comment: I'd say you can't, not with out a reference to `base` to start with

Comment: How do I add reference pointing Extended to MyObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways:

- Have a reference of your `extended` class in `MyObject` class. When you instantiate `MyObject` variable in `extended` class, pass it the reference of `extended`.

Something like this:

```
class MyObject{
    private base baseObj;

    public MyObject(base baseObj){
        this.baseObj = baseObj;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //here I need to call method add from class base.
            //use baseObj to call the methods
    }
}


class base
{
    protected final void add(){}      
}


class extended extends base {
    private MyObject pObject;
    ...

    public extended(){
        pObject = new MyObject(this);
    }

    {
        pObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

- Declare the methods in `base` class `static`. This way you can call the methods without requiring an instance of the `base` class.

Something like this:

```
class MyObject{

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //here I need to call method add from class base.
        //call like this
        base.add();
    }
}


class base
{
    protected static final void add(){}      
}


class extended extends base {
    private MyObject pObject;
    ...

    public extended(){
        pObject = new MyObject(this);
    }

    {
        pObject.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

*One more thing:* This is off-topic, but you might want to read about [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/naming.html). Having class names start with lowercase is something that you wouldn't find in the naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

dummy code like this:

```
class MyObject{
    public void DoSomething(Base base)
    {
        base.add();
    }
}

class extended extends base {
    private MyObject pObject = new MyObject();
    ...
    {
        pObject.DoSomething(this);
    }
}
```